# Updatable Partitioned views for multi tenant database

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, multi-tenant

Using SQL Server 2016+

We currently have a multi-tenant database where each user is allocated their own schema.  We are using partitioned views to make accessing this data simpler,  We have the constraints etc in place that allow us to update the base tables through the view. A simplified version is below just using individual session tables.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.SESSIONS;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.SESSIONS_readonly;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.SESSIONS_editable;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.Session3;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.SessionAnon;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Session1;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS dbo.Session2;

/* Create tables, primary keys and constraints required for partioned views */
/* Sessions 1 & 2 would be the equivalent of "logged in" users - i.e. they have all their own data */
/* Session Anon is a dummy session that provides a template of data for any "not logged in" users */
CREATE TABLE dbo.SessionAnon (Session INT           NOT NULL
                                  DEFAULT 0
                                  CONSTRAINT ck_sessionAnon_ID CHECK (Session = 0)
,                             Name    NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
,                             Val     INT           NOT NULL
,                             CONSTRAINT PK_SessionANON
                                  PRIMARY KEY (Session, Name));

CREATE TABLE dbo.Session1 (Session INT           NOT NULL
                               DEFAULT 1
                               CONSTRAINT ck_session1_ID CHECK (Session = 1)
,                          Name    NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
,                          Val     INT           NOT NULL
,                          CONSTRAINT PK_Session1
                               PRIMARY KEY (Session, Name));

CREATE TABLE dbo.Session2 (Session INT           NOT NULL
                               DEFAULT 2
                               CONSTRAINT ck_session2_ID CHECK (Session = 2)
,                          Name    NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
,                          Val     INT           NOT NULL
,                          CONSTRAINT PK_Session2
                               PRIMARY KEY (Session, Name));
GO

/* Create partitioned view */
CREATE VIEW dbo.SESSIONS
AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.SessionAnon UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Session1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Session2; 
GO

/* Insert data into sub tables via view */
INSERT INTO dbo.SESSIONS (Session, Name, Val)
VALUES (0, 'Children', 2)
,      (0, 'Parents', 2)
,      (0, 'GrandParents', 4)
,      (1, 'Children', 1)
,      (1, 'Parents', 2)
,      (2, 'Children', 3)
,      (2, 'Parents', 1)
,      (2, 'GrandParents', 2);

SELECT * FROM dbo.SESSIONS;
GO
```

We also have anonymous users, who while having their own session preferences would share common data - products, prices etc.  The sessions for these users are configured by creating a view which points to the anonymous session data and overrides with their session id.

```
/* Session 3 is an anonymous user with a view created that points to the anon session with its own session ID rather than a seperate table with its own data */
/* This is done as the real data sets here a quite large and there is less overhead creating a view than copying the table. */

CREATE VIEW dbo.Session3
AS
    SELECT  3 [Session] , Name  , Val
      FROM  dbo.SessionAnon
GO

/* Add Session 3 to the view */

DROP VIEW dbo.SESSIONS;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.SESSIONS
AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.SessionAnon UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Session1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Session2 UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Session3;
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.Sessions

GO
```

The problem that we have is that we can no longer alter the data in the view as one of the tables has a constant applied to one of the fields (i.e. we override the anon session id with a new session id)

```
/* This will now fail as one of the tables in the view has a constant field */
INSERT INTO dbo.SESSIONS (Session, Name, Val)
VALUES (1, 'GrandParents', 1);

GO
```

The solution we have in place at the moment consists of creating an editable view (containing the logged in users) and a readable view (containing the editable users and anonymous users)

```
/* Create two views, one editable (contains logged in sessions only */
/* and one read-only which reads from eduitable and adds anon sessions */
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.SESSIONS_readonly;
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS dbo.SESSIONS_editable;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.SESSIONS_editable
AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.SessionAnon UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Session1 UNION ALL 
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Session2
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.SESSIONS_readonly
AS
    SELECT * FROM dbo.SESSIONS_editable UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM dbo.Session3
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.SESSIONS_editable (Session, Name, Val)
VALUES (1, 'GrandParents', 1);

INSERT INTO dbo.Session1 (Session, Name, Val)
VALUES ( 1 , N'Great Grand Parents' , 0 )

SELECT * FROM dbo.SESSIONS_readonly
```

This functions correctly and the execution plans "sort out" a lot of the complexity.  Statistics show that the two queries are close enough to identical not to worry.  This does however require that we maintain two sets of views for each table.  It would be preferable if this were not the case - i.e. one view to cover all.

Does anyone know of any solutions around this that are available and in general use?  We have tried "instead of" triggers to allow writing, but the generation of the dynamic sql and execution is far slower than we'd like.  Especially when there are many sessions.

Please note the data above is not indicative of our live tables merely the principals used.  We have thousands of simultaneous sessions and data tables with tens of thousands of rows, so efficiency is as important as ease of support.